# [Spring Cloud Gateway]: Destination endpoint in externalized route configuration is not allowed to be null or empty

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Our existing application is built using Netflix Zuul 1.x framework and there are couple of route configurations in the application which does not have target endpoint.
For example:

```java
zuul:
   routes:
      SampleRoute:
          path: /sample/route/**
```

The attribute **url** that includes target endpoint is not specified.
The requests matching with above route configuration are handled by a pre-filter. After processing the request the filter set sendZuulResponse flag as false which instructs Zuul framework to not route the request to any endpoint.

The application is now migrating to Spring Cloud Gateway framework and we tried to migrate above route configurations in the framework as follows:

```java
spring:
   cloud:
      gateway:  
         - id: SampleRoute
           predicates:
              - Path=/sample/route/**
```

However we encountered following exception during application bootup:

```java
Binding to target org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind parameters under 'spring.cloud.gateway' to org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayProperties failed:

    Property: spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri
    Value: "null"
    Reason: must not be null
```

Is there any possible way to achieve above route configuration?
Is it possible to disable routing to destination endpoint using any flag like provided by Netflix Zuul?

Comment: I use `no://op` as the uri

Comment: Thanks a lot @spencergibb for the suggestion.. We will surely give it a try.. Hoping that routing does not happen with such configuration..

Comment: It will not add no global filter is registered to use that uri scheme

Comment: Add is a typo, should be as.